# Performing integration on a function

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to perform integration to a fraction where:

f(x) = 2x/b^2 where x ϵ [0,x]

So the approach i thought of is:

∫2x - b^2 dt

∫2x^2/2 - b^2 dt

∫x^2 - b^2 dt

[x^2 - b^2]

so the final answer i obtained is:

x^2 - b^2.

I would like to know if i integrated correctly since I'm pretty bad at integration.

Comment: First of all could you maybe use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question so that it is more readable. Secondly I am a little bit confused why you have wrote $f(x)=\frac{2x}{b^2}$ and then continued to integrate $f(x)=2x-b^2$. Last but not least it is kind of weird to use $x$ as the variable of integration and simultaneously as the upper limit.

Comment: You define $f(x) = \frac{2x}{b^2}$, but then go on to integrate $2x - b^2$? Which one of these is your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would generally be better if you noted that you are integrating a pdf since I recognize the function from your other question.

The pdf is given to you as a function of the parameter $b$

$$p(X=x|b ) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{2x}{b^{2}} &  \textrm{ for  }  x \in [0,b] \\ \\ 0  &  \textrm{ for  everywhere else } \end{cases} \end{align}$$

The cumulative distribution function of a pdf is given as

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(u) du $$

substituting here

$$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} p(X=x|b) du  \\  \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{2u}{b^{2}} du$$

the negative infinity will drop out as it is zero there
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{b^{2}}\int_{\infty}^{0} 0 du + \frac{1}{b^{2}}\int_{0}^{x} 2u du$$
$$ F(x) = \frac{2}{b^{2}}\int_{0}^{x} u du =\frac{2}{b^{2}} \frac{u^{2}}{2}\Big|_{0}^{x}  $$
$$ F(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{b^{2}}$$

Now then the cdf is

$$ F(x)  =\begin{align}\begin{cases} 0 &  x \leq 0 \\ \\ \frac{x^{2}}{b^{2}}  &  \textrm{ for } x \in [0,b]  \\ 1  & x  \geq b\end{cases} \end{align}$$

The main parts are that you can take out the constant $\frac{2}{b^{2}}$

Comment: thank you for helping out. My bad as i didn't know that integration for a pdf would be a totally different thing. Thanks for the heads up. Cheers!

Comment: It was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your integration of the function $f(x)=2x-b^2$ is correct as you wrote

$$F(x)=\int2x-b^2~dx=x^2-b^2$$

Plugging in the limits leads to

$$\int_0^{x'}2x-b^2~dxF(x')-F(0)=(x'^2-b^2)-(0^2-b^2)=x'^2$$

Integrating your first given function $f(x)=\frac{2x}{b^2}$ is nothing more than integrating $2x$ with aconstant factor $\frac1{b^2}$.

If it is the case that your upper bound $x$ and your integration variable $x$ are the same I do not really know how to evaluate this integral.